# MatchParent matching with activity, not with the WrapContent Parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a adapter layout and inside it I add 4 elements that uses WrapContent(3x TextView and one a custom View). These 3 Views works fine, but the custom view isn't match to the container(LinearLayout) and let the TextView to do the work to choose the height of this layout.

When I use wrap_content in this custom view, this happens:

[image: Calculus error]

I tried to use this code to calculate the size of this view, using this:

```
@Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int desiredWidth = 100;
    int desiredHeight = 100;

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    //Measure Width
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
      //Must be this size
      width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
      //Can't be bigger than...
      width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
      //Be whatever you want
      width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
      //Must be this size
      height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
      //Can't be bigger than...
      height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
      //Be whatever you want
      height = desiredHeight;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
  }
```

But I REALLY want to this view match with the parent, without any other parameter.

I tried to to this too inside the method **onMeasure**:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
parent.getHeight; <- Return 0    >:(
```

Anyone can help me?